# The type of namespace 'PosExplorer' not found after adding Microsoft.PointOfService namespace

Tags: c#, winforms

Even After adding Microsoft.PointOfService namespace, the PosExplorer is invalid. y?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have to add Microsoft.PointOfServices.dll as reference by dowloading complete version of POS .NET 1.14.
Mistake was that i had downloaded typical version (instead of complete) and added Microsoft.PointOfServices.WMI.dll as reference (since it was the only dll found in the download).

Answer (score 0):

The installer does not include the SDK folder with the PointOfServices.dll by default — you have to [select it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42081).